# What is the non-recursive form of the sum-over-paths simulation algorithm?

Tags: simulation

In my previous question on this, I managed to come up with a simple [recursive algorithm](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/14847/4153) for the sum-over-paths method. However, what other snatches of material I can find online don't use recursion when explaining it. I've tried to come up with a non-recursive form of the algorithm but it always seems to just look like the standard Schrodinger method. What is the non-recursive form of the sum-over-paths algorithm?

Also, how does such an algorithm map semantically onto a diagram like this, from [Aaronson's quantum computing lecture 9](https://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec9.html)?

[image]