# Feynman method and polynomial time algorithm for XQUATH

Tags: quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory, quantum-circuit, quantum-advantage, random-quantum-circuit

Consider the Feynman algorithm for simulating quantum circuits, as given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%27s_algorithm).

Consider the XQUATH conjecture for random quantum circuits from [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.12085), given by

> (XQUATH, or Linear Cross-Entropy Quantum Threshold Assumption). There
> is no polynomial-time classical algorithm that takes as input a
> quantum circuit $C \leftarrow D$ and produces an estimate $p$ of
> $p_0$ = Pr[C outputs $|0^{n}\rangle$] such that \begin{equation}
>  E[(p_0 − p)^{2}] = E[(p_0 − 2^{−n})^{2}] − Ω(2^{−3n}) \end{equation}
> where the expectations are taken over circuits $C$ as well as the
> algorithm’s internal randomness.

It is mentioned in the paper that the Feynman method comes close to spoofing XQUATH. The authors remark:

> The simplest way to attempt to refute XQUATH might be to try $k$
> random Feynman paths of the circuit, all of which terminate at $|0^{n}
>  \rangle$, and take the empirical mean over their contributions to the
> amplitude.

Does this yield a polynomial time algorithm though? What is the time taken to compute each Feynman path? Assume that each gate is acts non trivially on at most two qubits.

On a related note, the wikipedia link, it is mentioned that the Feynman algorithm, in general, takes $4^{m}$ time and $(m+n)$ space --- I do not see why that is so.

Comment: A related question: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/14816/9474, where you can find why Feynman algorithm takes $4^m$ time and $(m+n)$ space.